# Keeping Track of Comparisons Performed in a Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison

I'm trying to track the amount of comparisons made for a simple c++ sorting function.

```
void sort(int arr[], int size)
{

int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = arr[startScan];

    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (arr[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = arr[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
    arr[startScan] = minValue;
}



}
```

I was playing around with the value I thought might return the number of comparisons made, and thought at first perhaps the number of comparisons would be held in `startScan`. Of course it isn't, start scan will only hold ever hold a maximum of size-1. That's definitely not the number of comparisons made.

I thought perhaps it would be found in the variable index. So I created `int temp = index;` because I was lazy and didnt want to work it through, but sure enough when I returned the value of temp it was also just size-1. Don't know why I expected any different, but I thought I would try.

Then I started thinking about it... do I even know where comparison is taking place?

Turns out I don't know if I do or not. I figure all of my comparisons happen in the second for loop,
`for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)` and even then really just the `if` statement nested inside.

Anytime the `if` statement runs, it's comparing something. SWEET, I thought. So I created `int temp = 0;` at the top of my function, slapped a `temp++` inside the if statement, and thought SURELY THIS WILL GIVE ME THE NUMBER OF COMPARISONS.

It gave me an encouraging number this time. When sorting a random list of 13 numbers (random as in I picked random numbers) my temp returned a value of 18. That to me has no linear relation to any of my other numbers as far as I can tell.

So here's my real question. Does this work? Does my final code do what I want it to do, and indeed return the number of comparisons made? Or have I merely found yet another arbitrary number that I just so happen to like more than the other numbers yielded by my other tests. I have no idea how to manually count the number of comparisons. I like the number, but for all I know it could be way off.

Final code:

```
int sort(int arr[], int size)
{
int temp = 0;
int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = arr[startScan];

    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (arr[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = arr[index];
            minIndex = index;
            temp++;
        }


    }
    arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
    arr[startScan] = minValue;
}

return temp; 


}
```

Comment: Each loop also has a comparison each time it iterates.

Comment: So I figure my first for loop will run 'size-1' times, my second for loop will also run 'size-1' times, and then however many times my if loop runs? 

Addem all up?

Comment: Well, also the `temp` variable right now is only being increased when the condition is true. A comparison happens when it is false as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increase your counter only if the array value is less than the `minValue` :

```
    if (arr[index] < minValue)
    {
        minValue = arr[index];
        minIndex = index;
        temp++;
    }
```

If you want to count the number of `arr[index] < minValue` comparisons you make, you should change the code to:

```
    if (arr[index] < minValue)
    {
        minValue = arr[index];
        minIndex = index;
    }
    temp++;
```

And maybe give the counter a better name, what about `counter` ? ;)

By the way, just in case you want to compare your sort with the `std::sort` you could count its number of comparisons like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool myCountingCompare(int a,int b){
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    std::cout << "number of comparisons : " << counter << std::endl;
    return a > b;
}

int main() {
    int array[3] = {1,2,3};
    std::sort(&array[0],&array[3],myCountingCompare);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's giving me a much larger and more reasonable number!